# what is "request" in request.session in Django?

Tags: django, httprequest

I just start to learn Django and i want to know that Where did "request" come from?

> def home(request):
> if "login" in request.session:
> return render(request, "home.html")
> return redirect("login")

thanks:)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view

Answer (score 0):

In Django, each view function takes an **HttpRequest** object as its first parameter, which is typically named **request**.

An HTTP request is made by a client, to a named host, which is located on a server. The aim of the request is to access a resource on the server. To make the request, the client uses components of a URL (Uniform Resource Locator), which includes the information needed to access the resource.

In python, it is defined as a class. HTTPRequest class has multiple objects. You can check them out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).